# Pivot_longer into an already existing column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I want to pivot multiple columns, two by two into an already existing couple, from this

```
have <- tribble(
  ~egtest,~egorres,  ~egorresu, ~hrorres,~hrorresu,~prorres,~prorresu,~uninteresing,
  "qt", 500,"msec",90,"bpm",100,"msec", "cat",
  "qtc", 370,"msec",NA,"bpm",103,"msec","dog",
  "pra",83,"msec",79,"bpm",97,"msec","cat"
)
```

To this :

```
want <- tribble(
  ~egtest,~egorres,  ~egorresu,~uninteresting,
  "qt", 500,"msec","cat",
  "qtc", 370,"msec","dog",
  "pra",83,"msec","cat",
  "hr",90,"bpm","cat",
  "pr",100,"msec","cat",
  "hr",NA,"bpm","dog",
  "pr",103,"msec","dog",
  "hr",79,"bpm","cat",
  "pr",97,"msec","dog"
)
```

For now my code is

```
colstopivotEG <- function(table){
  out <-  subset(colnames(table),grepl(pattern = "orres\\b",colnames(table)))
  out <- out[out != "egorres"]
  #print(out)
  return(out)
}
pivot_eg <- function(ndf){
  EG1 <- pivot_longer(ndf,
                      cols = colstopivotEG(ndf),
                      names_pattern = "(.*)orres",
                      names_to="egtest",
                      values_to="egorres")
  
  
  EG2 <- pivot_longer(ndf,
                      cols=ends_with("orresu"),
                      names_pattern = "(.*)orresu",
                      values_to="egorresu")
  ndf <- bind_cols(EG1,EG2 %>% select(EGORRESU_STD))
}
```

But I can't seem to be able to pivot into an existing column, I'm out of ideas and any help could be great thanks !

PS: There's a lot of column that don't want to be pivoted

Answer (score 3):

I would split the tibble into two by columns:

- The columns starting with `eg` (keep them as they are)
- The rest (pivot them).

Afterwards (after repairing the second tibble's names) we can bind the two tibbles together again.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

eg <- have %>% 
  select(starts_with("eg"))

rest <- have %>% 
  select(-starts_with("eg")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(),
               names_pattern = "(hr|pr)(.+)",
               names_to = c("egtest", ".value")) %>% 
  rename(egorres = orres,
         egorresu = orresu)

bind_rows(eg, rest)
```

which gives

```
  egtest egorres egorresu
  <chr>    <dbl> <chr>   
1 qt         500 msec    
2 qtc        370 msec    
3 pra         83 msec    
4 hr          90 bpm     
5 pr         100 msec    
6 hr          NA bpm     
7 pr         103 msec    
8 hr          79 bpm     
9 pr          97 msec
```

Comment: one could also do it with eg variables: `have %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_pattern = "(hr|pr|eg)(.+)", names_to = c("egtest", ".value")) %>% mutate(test = coalesce(test, egtest), .keep = "unused")`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm trying to adapt it with the real data, I have other column that I don't want to pivot in the df, should I keep ```everything()``` and the ```names_pattern``` will only pivot the cols with the specified name pattern or should I use the ```cols``` argument ? (I added an unpivoted var)

Comment: You can replace `everything()` with `-your_col_name`

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

bind_rows(have[c(1:3,8)],
  map(list(c(4:5,8), 6:8),
  ~ bind_cols(egtest = str_sub(names(have[.x])[1], 1, 2), have[.x] %>% 
    set_names(names(have[c(2:3,8)])))))

#> # A tibble: 9 × 4
#>   egtest egorres egorresu uninteresing
#>   <chr>    <dbl> <chr>    <chr>       
#> 1 qt         500 msec     cat         
#> 2 qtc        370 msec     dog         
#> 3 pra         83 msec     cat         
#> 4 hr          90 bpm      cat         
#> 5 hr          NA bpm      dog         
#> 6 hr          79 bpm      cat         
#> 7 pr         100 msec     cat         
#> 8 pr         103 msec     dog         
#> 9 pr          97 msec     cat
```

Comment: It's very good but I have 150 column that are unpivoted and 10 couples to simultaneously pivot, I guess i could find a way to, for each couple select the couple and the unpivoted cols, but it's haaard tho I'm trying